# Django multiple databases and "cannot execute in a read-only transaction" error

Tags: database, django

I used the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) to set up multiple databases in a master-slave configuration. My routers are set up correctly, and I can see that reads and write go to the correct respective database, but I am running into an error with some of my API calls:

`cannot execute [UPDATE or DELETE] in a read-only transaction`

In the API handlers where this happens, I am updating or deleting some other model as part of the same call, and Django seems to want to use a slave database for those transactions instead of master.

[A workaround I found](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database) is to chain `.using('default')` before `update()` or `delete()`, which basically forces Django to use the master database for the update or delete. But this feels hacky and bandaid-ish, so I want to make sure there isn't a better way to do this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have same issue. This django master-slave configuration is not for production use. In real life this configuration gots many issues.

Comment: It looks like this is a related manager bug - it allways select read database for all queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to do this without sprinkling the `.using('default')` around in code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following? This was copied out of the Django docs page:

```
import random

class MasterSlaveRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Reads go to a randomly-chosen slave.
        """
        return random.choice(['slave1', 'slave2'])

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Writes always go to master.
        """
        return 'master'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the master/slave pool.
        """
        db_list = ('master', 'slave1', 'slave2')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        """
        All non-auth models end up in this pool.
        """
        return True
```

Finally, in the settings file, we add the following (substituting path.to. with the actual python path to the module(s) where the routers are defined):

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.AuthRouter', 'path.to.MasterSlaveRouter']
```

Comment: Yes, I have set up the routers correctly. I'll update my question to say that.

Comment: Ok. I transferred a large project to cluster with write and read db replicas (amazon aurora rds). I added routers with db_for_read and db_for_write. I fixed MANY bugs related "object created in master but select in next view return doesn't exist" because read replicas has lags. But. Now I got error "cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction" on instance.binds.all().delete() query.

Django routers doesn't work as expected...

Answer (score 0):

Got this too and posted a ticket for django developers.
Here it is: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32965

There was an answer. There is django documentation saying .delete() and .update() use same database (allways readonly!) that was used to retrieve the object. So this is not a bug, but future because they say it documented.

So there is two ways to solve this problem:

1. Add using('xxxx') before every .delete() and .update()
2. Replace .delete() by .clear() and .update() by .set()